# How to put quotation marks above and below letters d and p in word

Tags: ms-word

I want to make some text that has letters `d` with quotation marks (and apostrophe) above and below letters `d` and `p` in MS Office Word:

Example of what I am trying to make is this
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia0AA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The picture can be seen as a matrix and you can use Word's Equation editor to create the structure you want.

- In MS Word (tested in v2010), press **Alt** + **=**
- This will bring the inline Equation Editor
- Click inside the box and type **\matrix(&&@&&@&&)** followed by typing a space
- The above action will create a 3x3 matrix of cells where you can type
- In your case, you would need a 3x47 matrix of cells for each line in the picture, for that you will have to have '&' repeated 46 times, which again is repeated 3 times separated by @
- It should be something like: **\matrix(&&&&&&...&&&@&&&&&&...&&&@&&&&&&...&&&)** followed by a space
- You can then fill in the cells just like you do in a Excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Use an equidistant font like Courier New. Make three lines:

```
"  '     "   '  '
d  p  d  p p d  p
'  "  "  ' ' "
```

As you can see, top line is too high. Create special style for first lines with negative *Position* atribute.